# ESP8266 cannot connect to an existing network after using AT command

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi, arduino-pro-mini, node.js

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.agcross.com/2015/09/the-esp8266-wifi-chip-part-2-connecting-to-a-network/) to connect the ESP8266 to a wifi network using AT commands. I used the below schematics (without the connection between ESP's CPIO 0 and Arduino's Ground):

[image]

After that, I was able to follow through the tutorial and got this response in the Serial Monitor:

[image]

That means my ESP8266 has successfully connected to my Wifi named W3. However, I decided to switch the mode of my ESP8266 from Network Device (mode 1) to Both network device AND Access Point (mode 3) (at this point I called AT+CWJAP? and can still see that it's connected to W3 wifi). I then was able to see the ESP wifi in my wifi list as (AI-THINKER_4C8CF2) but when I connected to it, I cannot connect to the internet. I'm wondering what the problem is and would appreciate any help.

*Note:* **The reason why I switched to mode 3 is because I want to control an Arduino Pro Mini (instead of Arduino Pro) using NodeJS.** I followed [another tutorial](https://medium.com/@imkiran/connecting-johnny-five-arduino-raspberry-pi-etc-over-wifi-to-the-pc-using-esp8266-a10348fdb300) and I figured that I need to connect to an ESP8266 access point.

I uploaded the StandardFirmataSketchPlus to my Arduino Pro Mini, with the baud rate set to 115200 (which is the same baud rate with my ESP8266). The schematic I used is similar to the one below, except I used a 3.3V Pro Mini and a Lipo battery, instead of a 5V:

[image]

The nodejs code is below:

```
var VirtualSerialPort = require('udp-serial').SerialPort;
var firmata = require('firmata');
var five = require("johnny-five");
var sp = new VirtualSerialPort({
  host: '192.168.1.243' //I got this number from the AT command (STAIP above)
 });

var io = new firmata.Board(sp);

io.once('ready', function(){
    io.isReady = true;

    var board = new five.Board({io: io, repl: true});

    board.on('ready', function(){
        var led = new five.Led(12);
        led.blink(3000);
    });
});
```

This code is to test the connection between Arduino and Nodejs and when I run this file, it doesn't work.

Comment: just leave esp and your computer connected to your W3

Comment: @ Juraj I tried that. I connected my esp and computer to the W3 wifi and run the javascript code (that I added to my question) and it still can't connect to the internet.

Comment: what has internet to do with what you try to do?

Comment: you missed this line in the tutorial "I assume you have already flashed standard firmata on your Arduino"

Comment: Spend some time researching what each line of your Arduino sketch does. If you're using that sketch with that schematic you clearly don't understand the most basic principles of what it's intended to do. You're just using the Uno as a USB-serial adapter and the sketch on the Uno is doing absolutely nothing useful.

Comment: @per1234 sure with reset connected to ground every sketch is useless :-)

Comment: @per1234 I actually forgot to add that I used a different sketch for my Arduino Pro Mini. The sketch that I used above (on my Arduino Uno) is only used when I run the AT command to connect my ESP8266 to W3. I used StandardFirmataPlus sketch when I tried to control Arduino using nodejs. So I did flash the standard firmata on my Arduino, with the same baud rate with my ESP8266 (currently 115200).

Comment: But I understand that I only used my Arduino Uno as USB-TTL connector so I will edit my question. @Juraj I need the internet to control arduino using nodejs and chrome puppeteer.

Comment: ok. so you have Firmata in Atmega, AT firmware in ESP and the 'blink led' js on computer. does the led blink? or where is the error?

Comment: @Juraj yes correct. The LED doesn't blink. And the terminal doesn't show any error.

Comment: does this io.once() mean that the led blinks only once? I you sure it did not blink?

Comment: @Juraj once() function in javascript is executed only once. That means the board variable is only created once. But the function inside board.on('ready',function()) should allow the led to blink infinitely. I only knew this because it works without the esp8266, when I tried to control Arduino using nodejs *while the arduino is connected to my laptop*

Answer (score 1):

you have Firmata in Atmega, AT firmware in ESP and the 'blink led' js on computer.

you did not follow [the tutorial](https://medium.com/@imkiran/connecting-johnny-five-arduino-raspberry-pi-etc-over-wifi-to-the-pc-using-esp8266-a10348fdb300) properly. it requires [jonny-five firmware](https://github.com/anaganisk/johnny-five-esp8266.git) in esp8266

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31011)

Comment: I edited the answer

Comment: @Juraj I did upload the johnny-five firmware on my first ESP8266 but then I couldn't connect to an existing wifi network using the method that the author mentioned in the article. I then tried to use AT command but failed. I figured that maybe when I flashed the Johnny-five firmware on the ESP, I wiped the firmware that needed to run the AT command. Then I bought another ESP8266 just to test. This time I used AT commands to connect to an existing network, but as you can see, it cannot connect to the internet, or my arduino.

Comment: AT firmware, jonny-five or your sketch. those are only programs in the esp. what you flash there, runs there. I do not know the johnny-five firmware.